# Overwrite a column in Postgres from a column in a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a large table, and I wish to update only a single column. The values for that column is present in a CSV file. I want to avoid a single insert to event column because it would take a long time. I would prefer something like a COPY so that I can directly dump the new values over the older values. But dumping a specific using copy appends it to the end of the table rather than overwriting it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are the values in the csv file and the table mapped? Is there a common column present? If so, mention that.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:** Insertion is faster than update in DB so can follow below steps:

1. Load CSV to a temp table.Not all columns are required just primary
   key and the column which need to be updated in main table.
2. Rename main table to main_temp
3. recreate main table (no records now)
4. Join main_temp and temp table based on primary key and insert into
   main(select particular column from temp table instead from main table)
5. drop main_temp